# MySQL selecting tags

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, group-by

I've table with tags. It has columns id, tagTypeId and tagName. Each item can have many tags.
For each item I want to select first tags with tagTypeId 1, 2 and 3. I tried adding 3 almost identical left joins inside my query which worked pretty good but it was dramatically slow (like 5 seconds with not small amount of data in tables)

it is something like

```
select i.*, tag1.name, tag2.name, tag3.name from items i
left join (select t.id, t.tagName as name from tags t where t.tagTypeId=1) tag1 on ...
left join (select t.id, t.tagName as name from tags t where t.tagTypeId=2) tag2 on ...
left join (select t.id, t.tagName as name from tags t where t.tagTypeId=3) tag3 on ...
```

How can I achieve it better, in one join?

Comment: What do you mean with 'select first tags'? ordered by what?

Answer (score 0):

if you do something like

```
select i.*, tag.name, tagTypeId
  from items i left join (select t.id, t.tagName as name 
                            from tags t where t.tagTypeId in (1, 2, 3)) on ...
order by i.itemid, tagTypeId
```

you'd get a few rows per item, which can be transposed easily in a program.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT id id1, tagTypeId tag1 FROM items WHERE tagTypeId = 1 LIMIT 1) X1,  
(SELECT id id2, tagTypeId tag2 FROM items WHERE tagTypeId = 2 LIMIT 1) X2, 
(SELECT id id3, tagTypeId tag3 FROM items WHERE tagTypeId = 3 LIMIT 1) X3
```

This will give you what you want, but in different columns.

Comment: in fact order doesnt matter so much to me, it can be tag with smallest id

Answer (score 0):

Here's another take on this. It is reliant on grouping to 'pivot' the tags 1..3 across and `Max()` to exclude the nulls.

```
select i.ItemId, i.ItemName,
    MAX(CASE WHEN(t.tagTypeID = 1) THEN t.TagName ELSE NULL END) AS Tag1Name, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN(t.tagTypeID = 2) THEN t.TagName ELSE NULL END) AS Tag2Name, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN(t.tagTypeID = 3) THEN t.TagName ELSE NULL END) AS Tag3Name
from items i
    INNER JOIN tags t
    on t.ItemID = i.ItemID
where t.tagTypeId IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY i.ItemID, i.ItemName
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96ef6b/8)